# Generating multiple lines for repeat observations in only some factor levels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am generating density plots for observations. The observations belong to a species and some are also connected to an individual ID.

With the data below, I want to generate a line for each level of IndID for species One and Two, and only a single line for Species Three, which does not include IndID. [There are related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11478402/ggplot-multiple-lines-for-one-color-class) on SO, but not with reproducible data and looking for different results.

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(Species = c(rep(c("One", "Two"), each = 2, length = 30), rep("Three",50)),
                  IndID = c(rep(letters[1:5],each = 6),rep(NA,50) ),
                  Value = sample(1:20, replace = T))
```

Keeping the color ascetic on the Species level, I want to create multiple lines for Species One and Two (green and red) and a single blue line for species Three.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(Value)) + geom_density(aes(color = Species), size = 1.25) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("darkgreen","blue", "red"))
```

[image]

Comment: Use the `group` `aes`thetics: `aes(color = Species, group = interaction(IndID, Species))`. See `?aes_group_order`.

Comment: Yes. This is perfect. much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to tell them apart, you can set the `linetype` to `IndID`. Note, however, that you will need to change the `NA` to some other value to (easily) get it to plot.

I also expanded your data a little bit to give enough values per individual to show meaningful lines. I also used `geom_line(stat = "density")` instead of `geom_density()` because it omits the line along the bottom and gives legends with lines instead of boxes.

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(Species = c(rep(c("One", "Two"), each = 2, length = 60), rep("Three",50)),
                  IndID = c(rep(letters[1:5],each = 12),rep("NA",50) ),
                  Value = sample(1:20, 110, replace = T))


ggplot(dat
       , aes(x = Value
             , color = Species
             , linetype = IndID)) +
  geom_line(stat = "density"
            , size = 1.25) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("darkgreen","blue", "red"))
```

gives

[image]

If you want the lines to all be solid, you can run:

```
ggplot(dat
       , aes(x = Value
             , color = Species
             , linetype = IndID)) +
  geom_line(stat = "density"
            , size = 1.25) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("darkgreen","blue", "red")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = rep("solid", 6)) +
  guides(linetype = "none")
```

(or use `group` as @Henrik suggested in zir comment)